# SAPUI5 VizContainer - remove preset chart options (sap.viz.ui5.VizContainer)

Tags: json, configuration, sapui5, graph-visualization

I am using the VizContainer to visualize my data in SAPUI5 ([VizContainer-Link to demo page](https://sapui5.netweaver.ondemand.com/sdk/#test-resources/sap/viz/demokit/VIZContainer.html))

I got 2 questions:

- How to reduce the preset charting options (e.g. I do not want to offer all kind of Heatmaps and additionally I do not want to offer all kind of scatter plots) - I did not find any option to configure this... (answered)
- How to configure the X-axis correctly? (see example below)

X-Axis configuration from the link example on SAPUI5 demo kit page, easily inserts a second dimension into the dataset, but I think in a dynamic scenario this is quite difficult. My data has one dimension which is the month (in this month I have different y-axis-values), this works fine.

```
var  data =  [[
{"name":"Country","type":"Dimension"},
{"name":"Quater","type":"Dimension"},
{"name":"Profit","type":"Measure"}, 
{"name":"Revenue","type":"Measure"}],
  ["Country1","Q1" 141.25, 35],
  ["Country1","Q2", 41, 25],
  ["Country2", "Q1", 133.82, 45],
  ["Country2", "Q2", 33.82, 89],
];
```

My Data, which works properly for offering "Complete Timeframe" as x-axis. oJSON[i].Title contains the Month name (e.g. "10/2014")

```
var  data =  [ [ {"name":"Complete Timeframe","type":"Dimension"},
                 {"name":"Month1","type":"Measure"}, 
                 {"name":"Month2","type":"Measure"},
             ],
                 [ oJSON[0].Title, oJSON[0].Month1, oJSON[0].Month2],
                 [ oJSON[1].Title, oJSON[1].Month1, oJSON[1].Month2],
                 [ oJSON[2].Title, oJSON[2].Month1, oJSON[2].Month2],
             ];
```

What I want to achieve is being able to have multiple x-axis dimensions based on the months (e.g. in my VizContainer offer "Complete Timeframe" but also the single values such as "08/2014", "09/2014" ... is this possible? Anybody some experience with it?

**Answer on Question 1:** 
If there are any better solutions, please let me know!! I did not know how to achieve it in another way

```
    $("#content").find(".viz-controls-switchbar-switcher-container").children(':nth-child(4)').hide();
    $("#content").find(".viz-controls-switchbar-switcher-container").children(':nth-child(5)').hide();
```

Comment: hi @zyrex, did you got any other way to hide those charts?

Comment: I am also looking for an answer... Now doing it with CSS